# Storefront API: querying for variable parameters?

Tags: graphql, shopify, apollo, nuxt.js

The Shopify [Storefront API examples](https://github.com/Shopify/storefront-api-examples) show an App.js view listing all products on one page. In these examples, products are added to the cart from this index page, and there is no product detail page. Unlike the examples, I want to click through to a product details page from an index of products.

The products index was easy. But I'm having *alot* of trouble understanding how to create a page per product.

Seems I can't use a graphql query with a variable on Shopify Storefront. For example, this fails:

`query myQuery($id: ID!) {
  Product(id: $id) {
    id
    title
  }
}`

I'm using [nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) and [vue-apollo](https://akryum.github.io/vue-apollo/guide/apollo/queries.html#simple-query) to build the frontend.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The query you've provided is missing the actual variable value that you're querying.

The body of the HTTP request to the GraphQL endpoint should look like this:

```
query:"query myQuery($id: ID!) {
  Product(id: $id) {
    id
    title
  }
}"
variables:{id: "ce03707f-971e-4c64-853c-06a8c2e21448"}
```

Edit: Vue specific example:

```
// Apollo-specific options
apollo: {
  // Query with parameters
  ping: {
    // gql query
    query: gql`query PingMessage($message: String!) {
      ping(message: $message)
    }`,
    // Static parameters
    variables: {
      message: 'Meow',
    },
  },
},
```

from: https://akryum.github.io/vue-apollo/guide/apollo/queries.html#query-with-parameters

Comment: Thanks @RozenMD. 

I'll need then need to dynamically define the id variable for the product based on the route id. Something like this I presume?

`export default {
  apollo: {
    myQuery: {
      query: myQuery,
      prefetch: ({ route }) => {
        return {
          id: route.params.id
        }
      },
      variables: {
        return { id: this.id }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: How the hell does one format code here on stackoverflow? 

Comment: @CallumFlack almost there, I've updated my comment with how you'd do it in Vue